# AJAX code not working in relation to JSON and PHP when retrieving data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a search. The user searches for a city and the top 10 attractions for that city appear in divs. I want one attraction per div, before I tried to add any JSON the data was all appearing in one div.

Within my AJAX code, I am getting the alert meaning there is some sort of error, but I am not sure what. This is my AJAX code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'searching.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('#return').html(data.html);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $('#return').html('');
        alert('Error Loading');
    }
});
```

Within the searching.php is where I connect to the database and where I retrieve the data from. Within an if statement, if there is a result in the database matching the one that was entered into the search bar then return this information.

```
else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $attraction_name = $row['attraction_name'];
        $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}' height='100' width='100'>";
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $long = $row['long'];
        $cost = $row['cost'];

        $output .= "<li>$attraction_name $lat $long $cost $img</li>";

    }

    $json = array();
    $json['html'] = '<li>' . $output . '</li>';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $json );
}
```

Within the HTML there is a div id = #return. I would like to place the attraction name, the image of the attraction, where it is on the map and the cost of the attraction within a div. But each div needs to be different as there is 10 different attractions. Ultimately I would love to know how to add separate divs to match a certain row of data in MySQL. However, if I could figure out why there is an error in my AJAX, that would be great.

Comment: _"but I am not sure what"_ Then why don't you have a look at the three parameters of the error callback? At least `textStatus` and `errorThrown`

Comment: Examine what the actual error is.  Your `error` callback has these parameters: `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`  What's in them?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the response from the server?  Is there anything in your PHP logs?  When you get an error, start by reading the error.

Comment: if you want to work with each result, and each part of the result separately, don't send an object with single property which is your html string ... in javascript, you'd be looking at an object that looks a bit like `[{name: "the attraction name", lat: 12.123, long: 12.123, cost: 1000.00, img:some_url}, { ...}, {...} i.e. repeat object n times for n attractions..]` - at least you wont end up with invalid HTML (li shouldn't be a direct child of li)

Comment: @JaromandaX so i have the same thing I have in my database in my javascript code? Isn't there a better more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @David I am not sure what this code means though, as I found it on the internet and tried to use it with my return id. How do I find out the response from the server?

Comment: huh? no idea what you mean .. the way you're doing it is 100% inefficient, so any change will be for the better - unfortunately I haven't used PHP in many years (surprised it's still a thing to be honest) so, I can't really help with specifics on how to "build up" the "object" in PHP

Comment: @SSS12_: Then I guess you'll want to start with some tutorials on the technologies involved.  Copying and pasting text that looks like code from the internet without knowing what it does not only isn't an effective means of programming, it's generally a *very bad idea*.

Comment: Content type returned from PHP is application/json, but in ajax callback you are expecting as html. You may have to update the response header to return html or may update your ajax call with responseJSON..

Comment: @JaromandaX I know my code doesn't work, but I just thought I could retrieve the data from my database rather than writing the exact same data and adding it to my javascript file and then calling the javascript file. Wouldn't that mean I wouldn't need a php file?

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan - data.html actually **is** html :p

Comment: @SSS12_ - I never said you need to do that, did I? you must have misread what I wrote ... you need to JSON encode an array that has the various parts of the data as properties of objects inside the array

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan I changed the header to html in the php file and now it is returning all the information into the first div. Is there anyway I can separate the data into different divs?

Comment: @JaromandaX Would you be able to write out an example? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You’re not sending any parameters via ajax, just an empty post to searching.php.  You’ll want to add a `data` property to your ajax object, something like `data: $("#myform").serialize()`

Comment: @James instead of #myform do I add #return? this is my id that I am using to show the data from the database into my html divs

Comment: `#myform` is the html id attribute of the form that you want searching.php to process.  It’s just an example there are many possible ways to build the data property.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have created a pastebin which shows all my divs. Ideally I would like to keep the styling of them, but just insert all my data into it instead. I realise why all my information is going into the first div because I have called the id return within that div and only that div. But I am just not sure how I can separate each row of data into each div  https://pastebin.com/AYmRwBpL

Comment: @James would you be able to look at my pastebin in the above comment, is my id going to be #Attractions?

Comment: The data you send to php (to do the search) comes from somewhere, and the data you receive back from php goes somewhere else.  You’re asking me about the second, my comment was about the first.

Comment: @James Oh right, so the field has an id of search and the search button has an id of submit. Are you telling me I need to change the #myform in data: $("#myform").serialize() to either search or submit?

Comment: see where I said `unfortunately I haven't used PHP in many years so, I can't really help with specifics` - that was only an hour ago, I haven't brushed up on my PHP knowledge since then in order to write code for you

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php


$json = array('hmtl' => '<li>' . $output . '</li>');
echo json_encode( $json );
    
?>
```

Have you tried like this to define your array ?

If i 'm right your project will display a different answer in different div in function of an id ? imo To solve that you need to create a loop in your ph file to return a complete array with all your information.

```html
 $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}' height='100' width='100'>";
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $long = $row['long'];
        $cost = $row['cost'];

        $output .= "<li>$attraction_name $lat $long $cost $img</li>";
```

have you seen the $img and $image ?

Comment: I tried this, but fixed the spelling of it and it didn't work

Comment: what is exactly didnt work ou get nothing back ? please var dump at the end of your file var_dump( $json );

Comment: No so I had all the data going into one div using the code I have above but after I used your code, it wasn't returning anything

Comment: ok nevermind ,you want to move each information in a different div isn't it ?

Comment: Yea that is what I want to do

Comment: I am using the code above, and every time I type in a city, and click search the alert error comes up (from the ajax) and then when I click ok all the data appears in the one div, but not before I click ok on the error message

Comment: please var dump $json

Comment: I did do this at the end of my php file but nothing happened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161635/discussion-between-sss12-and-robin).